# Linear search on sorted list vs unsorted list -- why is sorted slower?

Tags: c++, list

So I created some random ints and put them into a list. I made a copy of it, then I sorted the original list. When i searched for a specific item through the sorted list, it was much slower than when I did in the unsorted copy. Why does this happen? Here's the code I used and some runtimes at the end.

```
int main(){
   const int SIZE = 100000, MAX_ELM = 10000000;
   list<int> sortedList;
   list<int> unsortedList;
   int indexToFind, itemToFind;

   srand(time_seed());
   indexToFind = SIZE/2;
   //initialize list
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){      
      if (i == indexToFind){
         itemToFind = randomNum(0, MAX_ELM);
         sortedList.push_back(itemToFind);
      }
      else
         sortedList.push_back(randomNum(0, MAX_ELM));
   }

   unsortedList = sortedList; //copy ctr
   sortedList.sort();
   clock_t start, end;
   int sortedItemIndex = 0;

   //search for item in sorted list
   start = clock();
   list<int>::iterator it;
   for (it = sortedList.begin(); it != sortedList.end(); ++it){
      if ((*it) == itemToFind){
         break;
      }
      sortedItemIndex++;
   }
   end = clock();

   cout << "index: " << sortedItemIndex << "  item: " << itemToFind << endl; 
   cout << (double)(end - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl << endl;

   //unsorted
   start = clock();
   for (it = unsortedList.begin(); it != unsortedList.end(); ++it){
      if ((*it) == itemToFind)
         break;
   }
   end = clock();

   cout << "index: " << indexToFind << "  item: " << itemToFind << endl;
   cout << (double)(end - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

}
```

Here are my functions for seeding rand(), although i don't think they're of importance

```
int randomNum(int min, int max){

   return rand() * (1.0 / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)) * (max - min);
}

unsigned time_seed(){ // implementation from online
   time_t now = time(NULL);
   unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&now;
   unsigned seed = 0;
   size_t i;

   for (i = 0; i < sizeof now; i++)
      seed = seed * (UCHAR_MAX + 2U) + p[i];

   return seed;
}
```

My runtimes are:

sortedList - index: 44315  item: 4439392 time: 0.047 sec

unsorted - index: 50000  item: 4439392  time: 0.028 sec

Comment: Are you testing on a machine with turbo boost?

Comment: Are you testing in release configuration? I [can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db28de3a8bd59904) your issue. Also are you always getting such results?

Comment: @James No. I'm using an i7 with 2 GHz and 6gb ram

Comment: Well you *do* more operations when searching the sorted list. When you search the unsorted list you don't have an index you increase every iteration.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ok so the index seems to be a bit of a problem. my idea was that the sorted list would take less time either way because of branch prediction

Comment: Also, testing with random numbers can always lead to false results. What if the number is small, and will end up early in the sorted list? Then the searching the sorted list will be very quick. Or if the looked after value is large, then it will end up late in the sorted list, and the searching will take longer time.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that is true, but the possibility of getting a duplicate is SIZE/MAX_ELEM which is 1% in this case so fairly unlikely. in my runs the index was roughly the same. i'd be glad to find a new way to test this though, im very curious about the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little rusty on the topic here, but as far as I'm aware, c++ lists are doubly-linked lists, which means there is no guarantee that your data is contiguous in memory.
It's fairly probably that the memory allocated for both lists is initially fairly (if not entirely) contiguous, which means the CPU doesn't have to seek through RAM very much.
Because of the nature of lists, sorting it does not physically move the data around, but rather just updates what each element is pointing at. As a result, when you sort the list, the elements are pointing all over the place in memory, meaning the CPU will have to grab new RAM for just about every operation.

Ordinarily that's not a huge deal, but when you're repeating it on average 50000 times that's a lot of CPU cycles wasted just waiting for the RAM to respond etc.

Comment: oh ok so basically going from element to the next takes longer simply because it is not contiguous? that kind of makes sense, but i don't understand why the CPU needs to grab new RAM for every operation

Comment: Going from element to element in random order reads a full cache line almost every time; also it throws some other cache line, that contains unvisited elements out of the cache. To demonstrate this, one can re-linearize the sorted array into a new array, which will most likely contain the elements in linear order. If the input is unbiased, the benchmarked times of sorted vs. unsorted -relinearized array should match.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see any problem with your code, however the order of tests might matter. Especially on such a short running times and especially if your computer is running with processor capable of dynamically changing its performance state.

Many Intel processors are equipped with technology called `turbo boost`, which basically makes the processor more powerful, when there is performance demand and than, in order to save energy, goes back to lower performance state when there is no need for it any more. For more information please refer to [this wiki site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost).

So conclusion - Try changing tests order or/and  setting your processor governor to performance and also increase the size of your testing set. 0.0... running times are really quite low and many weird phenomena might take effect.

Also consider storing your integers in something more convenient such as vector. Storing integers in list seems to be quite a waste of space unless you have a good reason to do it that way.

Comment: thanks for the info. i just wanted to test this with lists though because i'm using lists in my project not vectors. ill try to make a new implementation. should i keep the index constant so that i get rid of one dependent variable in this situation?

Comment: Well I would do that but that really depends on what you are trying to test.